# Modifying jQuery Mobile to allow headings to display on 2 lines before the ellipsis?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am trying jQuery Mobile for a project and am constructing a list.  For the  element, I would love to find a way to write to 2 lines, and then generate an ellipsis. Currently, the ellipsis generates after a single line like so:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...

I would like to know if there is a relatively feasible technique to have it display such as this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
> adipiscing elit. Phasellus pretium...

My HTML is as follows:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/thumbs/sample_photo.jpg" width="300" height="225" alt="Sample Photo">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus pretium consectetur.</h3>
      <p>Vestibulum risus mi, eleifend quis gravida.</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery Mobile's CSS for the  element is as follows:

```
ui-li-heading { 
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  display: block; 
  margin: .6em 0; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap;  
}
```

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the height to be equivalent to 2 lines of text. Add these two lines to the css for ul-li-heading:

```
    height: 32px; // font-size * 2
    display: block; // just to be sure
```

Of course, combine it with your original CSS above.

Comment: I am afraid it did not work, but thank you for the suggestion.